# Bitcoin Node Data Leakage

Tags: privacy, nodes

Besides an IP address and broadcasting transactions, what other pieces of information can be derived from a Bitcoin node in the network?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**As a peer:**

- You can derive the approximate location (GeoIP for IPv4, latencies and allocations for IPv6) unless the node is operating as a hidden service.
- You can query the node for it's version number.
- You can query the node for current date and time.
- You can query some of the nodes recent connections with the `addr` host discovery mechanism, giving you the IP address and the time the node last saw the peer.

**As someone with universal access to a nodes connection:**

- You can see which transactions (and addresses) belong to a user.

That's about it really unless you want to start poking around for other services, such as a web server on port 80 which would give you a lot of information about the owner, but only if it exists. `bitcoind` is designed to leak as little information as possible.